# Unable to set project name in the "grant permissions" dialog for Google Apps Script Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have an add-on for Google Sheets that's currently being tested within my domain. For this post, let's call it *My First Add On*. When users install the add-on they're prompted for permissions, but it always appears as "Untitled project" in the dialog box:

[image: Screenshot: Sign in with Google prompt]

The project name is set to *My First Add On* everywhere I can find:

- The Google Apps script project name
- The Google Cloud Platform project name (IAM > Settings)
- The Google Chrome Web Store add-on name (Developer Dashboard)

My add-on is published with 'private' visibility, available only to people in a given Google Group (my trusted testers).

I've searched through documentation and forums to see what I'm missing here, but can't find anything that covers this scenario.

This has to be something basic, but I'm completely stuck and the only support option available to me is to post here. I'd be grateful for any help, folks!

Comment: I've seen something similar, where the name of the script isn't updated if you test it before saving the name (ie, create a name when prompted rather than before testing). Try clearing your cache, closing out of the tab, etc, and then launching again. I'm not sure it's something you can fix in code or listings anywhere.

Comment: @Brian You nailed it! It was some kind of annoying caching bug. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as such. You deserve the kudos for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen something similar, where the name of the script isn't updated if you test it before saving the name (ie, create a name when prompted rather than before testing). Try clearing your cache, closing out of the tab, etc, and then launching again. I'm not sure it's something you can fix in code or listings anywhere.

Comment: for me I wasn't able until I edited the oauth scopes in the manifest file, closed the tab, went back later to the script project, click on run and then magically the name was updated.

Answer (score 1):

I *renamed my project* to a *dummy-value* like 'name' and then **restored** the correct project name manually (i.e. I renamed my project twice).

Afterwards my project name was showed correctly in the OAuth permission granting dialog.

(however to add honestly, I cleared my browser-cache before applying my method but deleting cache didn't solve the issue by itself)

Comment: As @ArchLinuxTux did, I renamed my project to "Dummy" and then renamed it back to what I want. That worked. I had tried clearing the browser cache before I did this and it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason may cause this problem: Your project name contains "Google".

Since it cannot be looked like an official application so you should avoid using "Google" in your project name, otherwise it will be displayed as "Untitled project" in the auth dialog.